# How best to perform memberwise assignment from superclass to subclass?

Tags: c#

I have a class AMX_Observation that is writ in stone.  (It's auto-generated from a dbml file and represents a remote DB table entry.)  I'd like to subclass that class to add a few fields.  But the class has 18 members, and it's only one of about a dozen classes I'll need to do this on, so constructing my subclass by manually copying the members one by one is not particularly attractive from a maintenance POV.

I know there's Object.MemberwiseClone, but it only copies from an object to another of the identical class.  I've not found anything that would copy the members of a superclass to a subclass.

FWIW, only shallow copying is required.

Comment: Looks like reflection is your only chance.

Comment: Favor composition instead of inheritance.  Wrap the type in a type that also has a few additional columns, rather than inheriting it just to adds a few columns.

Comment: Does the parent class actually have any functionality (besides its member properties) that you need in the subclass? If not, why not just use composition?

Comment: You could alter the way the code is generated from your dbml file ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31519/LINQtoSQL-Customize-the-Code-Generated-by-the-Desi)) to include a protected "copy constructor". It may require more work than the cost of maintaining it manually, though.

Comment: There are reasons I don't want to use composition -- mainly it would complicate other parts of the code that I'm trying to keep simple.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/

It's also available through NuGet if you are using Visual Studio.

If you have a subclass `AMX_ObservationDto` that inherits from `AMX_Observation`, you could copy the properties like this:

First, make a mapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AMX_Observation, AMX_ObservationDto>();
```

Now copy:

```
AMX_ObservationDto dto = Mapper.Map<AMX_ObservationDto>(amx_observationInstance);
```